# Jquery $(window).height() returns incorrect value when inside functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

When I call $(window).height() outside of any function (e.g. at the very beginning of the script), it gives the correct height. But when I call it inside any function, e.g.

```
$(window).resize(function (){

    window_height = $(window).height();
});
```

it always gives the same, incorrect result (2100). It does this in other functions (not only this one). I am testing this in Chrome (not sure whether problem occurs in other browsers).

Comment: Eh? That's very strange. `2100` as height looks mostly like height of `document`, but not `window`.

Comment: @VisioN that's right. $(document).height() gives 2100

Comment: [It does not work that way when I try it](http://jsbin.com/ehofik/1).  I suspect that there's something amiss elsewhere in your code; there's no way that simply being "inside functions" would make any difference here. (Check the console when you load that jsbin demo, and then start resizing the browser window.)

Comment: What exactly makes you think that it always returns 2100?  What other code did you use to check the value?

Comment: What happens when you put this code outside of any function but at the end of the page? I mean near the </body> tag?

Comment: Its working fine. You'll need to provide some other code you are using on your site for us to know where the flaw is.